# Populate UITextField by fetching a Core Data string

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uitextfield

I'm trying to populate a `UITextField` with data from a selected cell. When the table is populated, I use the array `var intentionsArray: [EIntentions] = []`, where `EIntentions` is my entity in Core Data. Whenever I try to set my text field to a specific index path value in the array, I get an error with converting from `EIntentions` to `String`.

Basically, what I want to do now is use my indexPath value that I am given to pull that specific value from the Core Data database. I cannot find a reliable way to do so and was wondering if there were any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this, where `selectedCellText` is a global variable that I pulled from my other .swift file

```
let selectedCellSet = intentionsArray[indexPath.row]
selectedCellText = selectedCellSet.value(forKey: "eIntentionCell") as? String)!
```